# Best way to add struct element to an array in c?

Tags: c

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char title[length];
    char createdDate[length];
    int completed;
} Todo;
```

and an array of these todos

```
Todo todolist[100];
```

and the element:

```
Todo newTodo = {...}
```

What's the best way to the element to the array?

Comment: You cannot add elements to arrays like this. You can 1. Keep track the number of actually used elements and add the number when adding elements. 2. Allocate arrays dynamically and use `realloc()` to add elements (You will also have to keep track the number of elements by yourself in this case)

Comment: `todolist[index] = newTodo`

Answer (score 1):

For a regular array, just do this:

```
todolist[index] = newTodo;
```

However, if you need it, it can be wise to add a field to indicate if the cell is initialized or not, so you know if it contains valuable info. You could do like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int initialized;
    char title[length];
    char createdDate[length];
    int completed;
} Todo;

Todo todolist[100] = {0}; // This initialization is important
```

And now we can du stuff like this to assign first free cell to a new `Todo`:

```
size_t i=0;

while( !todolist[i].initialized ) {
    i++;

    if( i >= 100 ) {
    /* Handle error */
    }
}

todolist[i] = newTodo;
```

Comment: You should do the range check *inside* the condition of `while` to avoid out-of-range access.